# Where can I edit the base data for my developer story?

Tags: support, developer-story

The new developer story page contains a link 're-import the data'. After that, your current modifications on your developer story are overwritten. But from which source these data are taken? Neither I can find any 'Edit Developer Story' nor do I have a Stack Exchange careers account which these data could come from.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have a Careers account? It looks like you created one back in 2012 but just didn't really use it.

Comment: @bluefeet, I have the same issue. Can you, please, provide the link to `Careers CV` service? I can't find any mention of this service on `SO`. Where Can I edit the original data of `Careers CV`, which is used for generation of `Developer Story`.

Comment: @MikeB. You can import your Careers data into your Developer Story where you can edit it. The Careers CV has been replaced by this new version.

Comment: @bluefeet, yes I know it. But my question is similar to the topic starter, I want to be able to edit the original source of the data, which is taken for the Developer story generation. Now, each time I press on `re-import the data` the service imports already outdated data, which has been edited via Dev Story UI. Please, add ability to sync the Dev Story with the source of `re-import the data` service.

Comment: @MikeB. I don't think I understand what you're asking for. When you re-import your data from Careers it wipes out the Dev Story data - if that's the data what you want to start your dev story with then that's the route you want to take.

Comment: @bluefeet, I mean the following: currently by clicking on `re-import the data` you can only update the data `Careers CV` → `Dev Story`, but I want to update the `Careers CV` it self, e.g. `Dev Story`→ `Careers CV`. Why? That the next time I'll click on `re-import the data` I'll get not absolutely outdated data but something more or less actual. If it's impossible, please, provide the button, which will completely delete the `Dev Story`/`CV` account and will allow creating it from the scratch.

Comment: @MikeB. The ability to import Careers CV data is temporary for users with that data available. It's not a permanent feature and will no longer be accessible at some point. The purpose of it was for users to be able to load their data to Dev Story once so they don't lose their previous data.

Comment: @bluefeet, OK, got it. But add ability to edit data not only in Dev Story view but in Traditional view as well.

Comment: That'd be a different [feature-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=developer-story) @MikeB. I'd post a request asking for that.

Comment: @bluefeet, done.
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337551/edit-cv-in-traditional-view-and-not-only-in-story-view