# Edit CV in Traditional view and not only in Story view

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, traditional-view

After introduction of ***Developer Story*** the only way to edit CV is via ***Story*** view. But for some users it is more comfortable to edit CV via ***Traditional*** view.

Please, add ability to edit data not only in ***Story*** view but in ***Traditional*** view as well.

Comment: At least story view should provide some comfortable editor. Tags field fits only two rows. Job editor is extremely narrow even with 24" monitor. From my point of view its Tranditional view should be used for edition, and story view is just a handy representation of classics. Not vice versa

Comment: Support it. Developer view is not very convenient for editing.